# Image sprite doesn't show in my canvas with PIXI JS

Tags: javascript, image, canvas, sprite, pixi.js

My image sprite (game.player_booba) doesn't appear and I do not understand why. In spite of the modification of its position in x and in y it does not appear.

```
game.player_booba.init();
game.player_booba.sprite.image.addEventListener("load", (event) => {
  window.requestAnimationFrame(game.loop);

});
```

My codePen:
    https://codepen.io/manonragnotti/pen/abbeEKO

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To be honest I do not see how this question is even related to PIXI. You've included it to your codePen project but you never actually used the library. All the rendering is done directly using the native 2d canvas api. And the reason why the character sprite is not drawn on the screen is because is drawn on a canvas, which is never added to the DOM. See on this line

```
buffer = document.createElement("canvas").getContext("2d");
```

you are creating a canvas element and then assign its 2d context to the variable "buffer", but the DOM element is never actually added to the document. So you need to do something like this:

```
bufferCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
buffer = bufferCanvas.getContext("2d");
window.document.body.appendChild(bufferCanvas);
```